# How to import submodules from d3 to easily create legend?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend, observablehq

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and D3 so please keep that in mind. I've created a visualization to show the visit frequency to particular locations in a warehouse and would like to add a legend using a continuous color scale.

[image]

I've looked at several blocks and could come up with something tangential, however I came across [this](https://observablehq.com/@mumairofficial/color-legend) webpage and would like to use the legend function. Naively, I tried adding

```
import {legend} from "@d3/color-legend"
```

which failed as expected. I am not sure what to do in order to make this import work. I've downloaded the latest d3.zip file and have tried the following sources without any success.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given the relative path of that module name that `import` will only work in a Observable's cell. If that's not your case, simply copy the whole function, which you'll find below (click "Show code snippet"), or save it as a file (and then you can do an `import` with the adequate module name):

```js
function legend({
  color,
  title,
  tickSize = 6,
  width = 320,
  height = 44 + tickSize,
  marginTop = 18,
  marginRight = 0,
  marginBottom = 16 + tickSize,
  marginLeft = 0,
  ticks = width / 64,
  tickFormat,
  tickValues
} = {}) {

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .style("overflow", "visible")
    .style("display", "block");

  let x;

  // Continuous
  if (color.interpolator) {
    x = Object.assign(color.copy()
      .interpolator(d3.interpolateRound(marginLeft, width - marginRight)), {
        range() {
          return [marginLeft, width - marginRight];
        }
      });

    svg.append("image")
      .attr("x", marginLeft)
      .attr("y", marginTop)
      .attr("width", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
      .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
      .attr("xlink:href", ramp(color.interpolator()).toDataURL());

    // scaleSequentialQuantile doesn’t implement ticks or tickFormat.
    if (!x.ticks) {
      if (tickValues === undefined) {
        const n = Math.round(ticks + 1);
        tickValues = d3.range(n).map(i => d3.quantile(color.domain(), i / (n - 1)));
      }
      if (typeof tickFormat !== "function") {
        tickFormat = d3.format(tickFormat === undefined ? ",f" : tickFormat);
      }
    }
  }

  // Discrete
  else if (color.invertExtent) {
    const thresholds = color.thresholds ? color.thresholds() // scaleQuantize
      :
      color.quantiles ? color.quantiles() // scaleQuantile
      :
      color.domain(); // scaleThreshold

    const thresholdFormat = tickFormat === undefined ? d => d :
      typeof tickFormat === "string" ? d3.format(tickFormat) :
      tickFormat;

    x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-1, color.range().length - 1])
      .rangeRound([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(color.range())
      .join("rect")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => x(i - 1))
      .attr("y", marginTop)
      .attr("width", (d, i) => x(i) - x(i - 1))
      .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
      .attr("fill", d => d);

    tickValues = d3.range(thresholds.length);
    tickFormat = i => thresholdFormat(thresholds[i], i);
  }

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - marginBottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
      .ticks(ticks, typeof tickFormat === "string" ? tickFormat : undefined)
      .tickFormat(typeof tickFormat === "function" ? tickFormat : undefined)
      .tickSize(tickSize)
      .tickValues(tickValues))
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").attr("y1", marginTop + marginBottom - height))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.append("text")
      .attr("y", marginTop + marginBottom - height - 6)
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .text(title));

  return svg.node();
}
```

However, there is another hurdle: currently that function will also only work in an Observable's cell. If you want it to work on a regular web page, change its returned value (or append the SVG as a side effect).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I've followed your suggestion and received an error ```DOM is not defined``` in the ramp function when creating the canvas. Do I need an additional source tag to fix this or is there another route? Thanks once again!!

Comment: @Manny Well, that's a different problem: `DOM` is a method of observable notebooks only (check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55865767/5768908). Here at Stack Overflow we keep just one problem per question, so if you face a different issue please feel free to post a new question, with all the relevant information. But this `DOM` issue is easy to fix: just append the `canvas` the regular way.

Comment: Thank you for the link and for teaching me about Stack Overflow etiquette. I replaced the ```DOM``` line with ```const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");``` which doesn't cause any errors however the legend is not displayed even though the legend svg is appended to the main div tag. Is this considered a different problem for another question? If not, do you know what could be causing this? [Here's a link to a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__js__/09aqdfrk/10/#&togetherjs=7Lwr1x7KTO).

Comment: @Manny yes, it's a different problem, not related to this current question, which was already answered. Thus, please ask it as a new question.

Comment: @ Thanks for letting me know. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443356/legend-not-appearing-when-using-document-createelementcanvas-instead-of-dom) to the new question.