# Legend not appearing when using document.createElement('canvas')

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, canvas, observablehq

I followed [this](https://observablehq.com/@mumairofficial/color-legend) Observable post to easily create a legend.

Since the line

```
DOM.canvas(1, n)
```

in the `ramp` works only on Observable, I replaced it with

```
document.createElement("canvas")
```

and also modified the SVG so that it's appended to the main div tag. These changed do not cause any errors however the problem is that the legend is not displayed even though the legend SVG is present in the raw HTML.

Here's the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/__js__/09aqdfrk/10/#&togetherjs=7Lwr1x7KTO) to a JSFiddle. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. If you're new, please [take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) _(you'll get a badge for doing so)_ and learn [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When seeking debugging help, always include minimal code needed to reproduce the issue [**in the question itself**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (links to JSFiddle are secondary)

Comment: @blex Thanks for the link, do you have specific suggestions on how I can improve my question?

Comment: When seeking debugging help, always include minimal code needed to reproduce the issue in the question itself

Comment: @blex Did I include too much code?

Comment: You did not include any code. Instead, you included links to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas is being created, that's not the problem. The problem is that, since you are now missing the width and height in...

```
const canvas = DOM.canvas(n, 1);
//these are w & h --------^--^
```

... you now need to set those yourself. For instance:

```
d3.select(canvas).attr("width", n)
  .attr("height", 1);
```

Here is a simplified version of that JSFiddle, showing that the canvas works:

```js
legend({
  color: d3.scaleSequential([1, 10], d3.interpolateReds),
  title: "Title"
})


function legend({
  color,
  title,
  tickSize = 6,
  width = 320,
  height = 44 + tickSize,
  marginTop = 18,
  marginRight = 0,
  marginBottom = 16 + tickSize,
  marginLeft = 0,
  ticks = width / 64,
  tickFormat,
  tickValues
} = {}) {

  const svg = d3.select(".scatter").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .style("overflow", "visible")
    .style("display", "block");

  svg.append("image")
    .attr("x", marginLeft)
    .attr("y", marginTop)
    .attr("width", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
    .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
    .attr("xlink:href", ramp(color.interpolator()).toDataURL());

}

function ramp(color, n = 256) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  d3.select(canvas).attr("width", n)
    .attr("height", 1);
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    context.fillStyle = color(i / (n - 1));
    context.fillRect(i, 0, 1, 1);
  }
  return canvas;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<div class="scatter">
</div>
```

By the way, there is no such element as `<legend-svg>`.

---

PS: This is the [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60424934/5768908) from you I'm answering on this subject. As you're new to JavaScript and D3, here is an advice: do not try to use that Observable notebook, that's way too complicated for your purposes. Just create the SVG, the canvas and a basic axis yourself, from scratch, it will be way easier.

Comment: thanks for the simple fix that is exactly what I was looking for. Additionally, thank you for the advise, I'll keep that in mind moving forward!